# App crashes with a include tag in the phone

Tags: java, android, android-layout, include

I have included a layout to the activity_main but everytime i try to run the app it crashes. I used several phone but the result is same. I tried by including a different layout it works fine. I am trying to add a simple login page.

Logcat is below:

> 019-08-04 22:53:39.178 25564-25613/? D/CACHE_HINTS: Entering madvise
>   file 2019-08-04 22:53:39.182 3242-4958/? D/SyncManager: userId - 0
>   auto - true 2019-08-04 22:53:39.183 3242-4958/? D/SyncManager: userId
>   - 0 auto - true 2019-08-04 22:53:39.184 2791-22291/? I/display: [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(0) 2019-08-04
>   22:53:39.184 25564-25613/? D/CACHE_HINTS: MADVISE_RAND file 0xc1f5c000
>   5341183 /data/data/com.facebook.katana/app_restricks/layouts.bin
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.209 3242-4958/? D/SyncManager: userId - 0 auto -
>   true 2019-08-04 22:53:39.233 3242-4958/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system)
>   Binder:3242_12 identical 2 lines 2019-08-04 22:53:39.234 3242-4958/?
>   D/SyncManager: userId - 0 auto - true 2019-08-04 22:53:39.244
>   25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is deprecated. Switch to
>   @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeReset(long) 2019-08-04
>   22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is deprecated.
>   Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeClearChildren(long) 2019-08-04
>   22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is deprecated.
>   Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeInsertChild(long, long, int)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeRemoveChild(long, long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeSetIsReferenceBaseline(long,
>   boolean) 2019-08-04 22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang
>   JNI is deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for boolean
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeIsReferenceBaseline(long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeMarkDirty(long) 2019-08-04
>   22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is deprecated.
>   Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeMarkDirtyAndPropogateToDescendants(long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for boolean
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeIsDirty(long) 2019-08-04
>   22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is deprecated.
>   Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeSetHasMeasureFunc(long,
>   boolean) 2019-08-04 22:53:39.244 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang
>   JNI is deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeSetHasBaselineFunc(long,
>   boolean) 2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang
>   JNI is deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeCopyStyle(long, long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for int
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleGetDirection(long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleSetDirection(long, int)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for int
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleGetFlexDirection(long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleSetFlexDirection(long,
>   int) 2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI
>   is deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for int
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleGetJustifyContent(long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleSetJustifyContent(long,
>   int) 2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI
>   is deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for int
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleGetAlignItems(long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleSetAlignItems(long, int)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for int
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleGetAlignSelf(long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleSetAlignSelf(long, int)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for int
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleGetAlignContent(long)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for void
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.jni_YGNodeStyleSetAlignContent(long, int)
>   2019-08-04 22:53:39.245 25564-25598/? W/facebook.katan: !bang JNI is
>   deprecated. Switch to @FastNative for int
>   com.facebook.yoga.YogaNative.

This is activity_login.xml

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/text_background"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_field"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_right"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Login_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:onClick="admin"
            android:text="Log in"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_right"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Forgot your Password?"
            android:textColor="@color/text_field"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_right"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Login_btn" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:background="#660066"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline_left"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noAccount"
            android:text="Do not have an Account?"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/footer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:text="SignUp Here"
            android:textColor="@color/text_field"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noAccount" />
```

This is activity_main.xml file

```
<include layout="@layout/activity_login"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post your logcat

Comment: 019-08-04 22:53:39.178 25564-25613/? D/CACHE_HINTS: Entering madvise file
2019-08-04 22:53:39.182 3242-4958/? D/SyncManager: userId - 0 auto - true
2019-08-04 22:53:39.183 3242-4958/? D/SyncManager: userId - 0 auto - true
2019-08-04 22:53:39.184 2791-22291/? I/display: [PrimaryDisplay]

Comment: There is a option on right top corner of logcat to show the logcat of only selected application or current application, select that and rerun app and then post your logcat, so that's how we can get to know about the errors.

Comment: i cant find that